# Webscraping inconsistently built tables using BeautifulSoup [gurufocus site]

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get three indicators from gurufocus site, and encountered an issue I'm not sure how to address properly - the thing is tables I'm scraping are inconsistent regarding how many rows they have.

I'm getting Piotroski F-Score, Altman Z-Score and Beneish M-Score from the summary page for each of tickers I have on my list - example site for AAPL ticker is [here](https://www.gurufocus.com/stock/AAPL/summary)

But, when I iterate through my tickers list, I encounter some stocks, for which the summary page has a table in which my values are one row earlier, see [here](https://www.gurufocus.com/stock/anss/summary) (there is no "interest coverage" row).

Initially, my code looks like this:

```py
    ls=['Ticker', 'Piotroski F-Score', 'Altman Z-Score', 'Beneish M-Score']

    dict_ls={k:ls[k] for k in range(len(ls))}
    df=pd.DataFrame()
    for j in range(len(symbols)):
        req = requests.get("https://www.gurufocus.com/stock/"+symbols[j])
        if req.status_code !=200:
            continue
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
        table = soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name=='table')

        rows = table[1].findAll(lambda tag: tag.name=='tr')
        out=[]
        for i in range(len(rows)-1):
            td=rows[i].find_all('td')
            out=out+[x.text for x in td]
        out=[symbols[j]]+out[21::3]
        out_df=pd.DataFrame(out).transpose()
        df=df.append(out_df,ignore_index=True)

    df=df.rename(columns=dict_ls)
    df.to_csv('guru-output.csv')
```

What's the best way to deal with such tables to consistently get those three values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could find the next tag after the `<a>` tag containing the name of the score you are interested in:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

ls=['Ticker', 'Piotroski F-Score', 'Altman Z-Score', 'Beneish M-Score']
symbols = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'ANSS']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=ls)

for t in symbols:
    req = requests.get("https://www.gurufocus.com/stock/"+t)
    if req.status_code !=200:
        continue
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
    scores = [t]
    for val in ls[1:]:
        scores.append(soup.find('a', string=re.compile(val)).find_next('td').text)
    df.loc[len(df)] = scores
df
```

And you get:

```
    Ticker  Piotroski F-Score   Altman Z-Score  Beneish M-Score
0   AAPL    6                   5.21            -2.82
1   MSFT    8                   6.01            -2.55
2   ANSS    7                   23.98           -2.3
```

Comment: Perfect, that's what I want, thank you very much!

BTW, as I'm trying to extend this: https://github.com/xang1234/Finviz-Scraper/blob/master/Finviz-Scraper.py with my three additional indicators, could you please help me to incorporate your solution to the code? I assume that requires some change in how finviz-scraper iterates through symbols, but I'm really stupid :(

Comment: @RudolfTheOne Please, accept my answer and ask a new question in order not to nest questions one inside the other. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I programmed a very similar program for my college project just a few days back.

I got around this problem by limiting the number of stocks viewed. I did that by making different programs for different stocks. I utilized the same structure for each, and modified the parameters according to each page.

This is the only way I think there is as of now. Since websites with a lot of data, like stock marketing ones for example, have a different structure for each page.
The web builders very rarely update the structures, they do it only when there is a major design update as I had noticed during the trial of my project.

Hope that helps you!